# Twitter4j via maven - classes are missing

Tags: maven, twitter4j

I have integrated twitter4j into my project via maven, using the depndencies / repositories as shown on the twitter4j homepage :

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>[2.2,)</version>
    </dependency>
..
    <repository>
     <id>twitter4j.org</id>
     <name>twitter4j.org Repository</name>
     <url>http://twitter4j.org/maven2</url>
     <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Unfortunately, not all resourcesfrom the twitter4j core project are available in my project. For example, the interface "StatusListener" is not. 
Can maybe someone give me a hint what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the `twitter4j.StatusListener` class moved to the `twitter4j-stream` artifact in version 2.2.0.  Add it to your dependency list.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this is not clear to me from the project page.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up searching at [Jarvana](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=twitter4j.StatusListener) and saw the different artifact ids.

Comment: oh okay, from there it is obvious - thanks again for your effort!